# ReactiveUI MessageBus and MessageBox with result

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, system.reactive, reactiveui

I've been using Rx and more specifically ReactiveUI for a while in a project and have got myself into a situation where I think I need some advice.

The problem is that, given a command is executed (a button is clicked) I want to show a message box, one which the user will answer Yes or No. Depending on the answer, I then want to do some more stuff. As I'm using MVVM with unit tests I'd like the MessageBox to be testable; i.e. to be replaced by some other code. This is essentially what I've got.

In my view model:

```
this.ExternalObservable = this.SomeOperationCommand
            .SelectMany(_ => this.UserWantsToContinueWithOperation())
            .Where(x => x)
            .Select(_ => this.SomeData)
            .Where(x => x != null);

private IObservable<bool> UserWantsToContinueWithOperation() {
        var subject = new Subject<bool>();

        var box = new GuiMsgBox("Continue?",
            result => {
                subject.OnNext(result == System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Yes);
            });

        MessageBus.Current.SendMessage(box);

        return subject;
    }
```

And the `GuiMsgBox` is essentially a wrapper around the `System.Windows.MessageBox` class which I listen to using the `MessageBus` in the UI and in my tests.

This all works fine when running the application, but in unit tests, as the bus is then using the Immediate scheduler, it's obviously not working the same way.

I feel there's some design glitch here, so any input on the actual problem; to show a message box, returning a result, which can be tested, would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell without seeing more implementation details, but I would consider using TestScheduler instead. In RxUI.Testing, this is as easy as:

```
(new TestScheduler()).With(sched => {
    // Write your test here, all the schedulers will be
    // implicitly set to your 'sched' scheduler.
});
```

Here's an example of a bunch of MVVM-related tests, testing a Pomodoro timer:

https://github.com/xpaulbettsx/ReactiveUI/blob/master/ReactiveUI.Sample/ReactiveUI.Sample.Tests/ViewModels/BlockTimerViewModelTest.cs

Here's another good example of MVVM-based testing [from my Rx book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430237473) (sorry about the plug),  specifically using CreateColdObservable in order to mock input (i.e. testing the scenario of "Click a button, wait 10 seconds, check result")

https://github.com/ProgRx/Chapter-9

Comment: Good idea, i'll try the `TestScheduler` for this particular problem. What else do you think about this way of getting the result from a dialog box? How do you do it when using ReactiveUI? I suppose it boils down to the `MessageBus` being deferred instead of immediate, which is the case in e.g. MVVMLight, is it not?